# Failed to resolve module specifier bootstrap, vue.js3 and netlify

Tags: npm, vuejs3, package.json, netlify

I am trying to deploy my vue.js 3 SFC  app to netlify.

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier
> "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css". Relative references must start
> with either "/", "./", or "../".

I only have bootstrap import in main.js file and it is like this:

> import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

> import "bootstrap"

when I changed the path in main.js file my local environment crashed so I did not have a courage to deploy it further.

My package.json looks like this:

````
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "vue": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.5.2",
    "vite": "^5.0.10"
  }
}```

What can I do to make it up and running?
````